# Android device provisioning as a dedicated device using Android Management API fails

Tags: google-play-services, android-management-api, android-for-work, android-enterprise

I am trying to build an Android Enterprise [solution set](https://developers.google.com/android/work/dev-options#1_android_management_api) using Android Management API and Android DPC in **Dedicated Device** mode.

following the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart), I created Project, Enterprise and Policy. Stuck at the device provisioning phase.

Device details: Minix X68i, Android 6.0.1 [rooted]

NOTE: **THERE IS NO WELCOME SCREEN OF SETUP WIZARD ON THE DEVICE**

As per the [Provisioning Methods](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#provisioning_methods), my device is eligible to be provisioned only by using NFC or DPC Identifier. Tried DPC Identifier but since there is no welcome screen after a factory reset, I tried it while adding a new account, it just rejects the **afw#setup** string altogether. Can not try NFC method as the device isn't equipped with NFC receiver.

I need a way to trigger the DPC identifier or NFC mode alternatively. any other way I can install the DPC manually and make it register the device under Device Owner mode?

Right now I tried with downloading the DPC app from https://play.google.com/managed/downloadManagingApp?identifier=setup but the app always chooses the Managed Profile mode, even if I manually set the DPC as the Device Owner and the "CloudDeviceAdminReceiver" as device admin. See the initial DPC logs below:

```
I clouddpc: [SyncAuthActivity] Has setup started: false
I clouddpc: [SyncAuthActivity] Was device ever compliant: false
I clouddpc: [SyncAuthActivity] Is admin active: true
I clouddpc: [SyncAuthActivity] Token key: null
I clouddpc: [SyncAuthActivity] Not a GMS intent, this might happen if we are launched from Play Store.
I clouddpc: [SyncAuthActivity] Not an admin yet. Start enrollment token managed profile provisioning flow.
```

I even tried to manually launch the `com.android.managedprovisioning/.DeviceOwnerPreProvisioningActivity`, the device says "oops! "this device is already set up"

Comment: in the welcome screen after a factory reset , did you tried this method (https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#qr_code_method) ?

Comment: There is no welcome screen or setup wizard present on the device. It just boots up and brings the default launcher after a factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

The Minix X68i looks like an Android TV device.

The Android Management API doesn't work with Android Wear, TV, or Auto devices.

Comment: I tried Miradore as well as Airdroid's EMM. They provide their own client app which I assume acts as DPC. The device is provisioned and works as expected.

Since Android's official DPC is the only app compatible with the MAnagement API, these other solutions must be using EMM API.